# Change post-login redirect from admin/my-account to admin/something in OrionJS

Tags: meteor

So I'm using Meteor with [OrionJS](http://orionjs.org/) framework and I can't figure out how to change the redirect after login to a page other than `admin/my-account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Options.set('adminHomeRoute', 'collections.yourCollection.index');`